# Removing everything after a character, including that character

Tags: java, regex, string

So I have a bunch of Strings that I want to parse into floats. Some of these strings have multiple decimal points, i.e.
`100.2.3`. I need to simplify this string down to only have 1 decimal point and truncate everything (including the decimal point) after it the second occurrence of the decimal. So, for example, 100.2.3 would simplify to 100.2

Also, there might be *more* decimals than just two. So, 100.2.3.4.3.4.2 needs to be simplified to 100.2 as well

Is there an easy way to get this done? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceFirst("^([^.]+\\.[^.]+)(.+)$", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA1bE5/3)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but it works:

```
String newString = string.split("\\.")[0] + "." + string.split("\\.")[1].split("\\.")[0];
```

Comment: This only works for one case: if there are 2 decimal points. If the string is "1.2.3.4" is will only return "1.2.3". What I needed was "1.2".

Comment: I tried it and it worked correctly for me, even with more decimals. Though I've edited the post, so you might have tried the old code I posted, that as you said is incorrect.